# Pandas dataframe- create new list column consisting of aggregation of strings from grouped column

Tags: python, pandas

I've been struggling with this one a bit and am feeling a bit stuck.

I have a dataframe consisting of data like this, named `merged_frames` (it is a single frame, created by concatenating a handful of frames with the same shape):

```
          fqdn               source
0         site1.org          public_source_a
1         site2.org          public_source_a
2         site3.org          public_source_a
3         site1.org          public_source_b
4         site4.org          public_source_b
5         site1.org          public_source_b
6         site4.org          public_source_d                                 ...                 
7         site1.org          public_source_c
...
```

What I am trying to do is create a new column in this frame that contains a list (ideally a Python list as opposed to a command delimited string) of the sources when grouping by the `fqdn` value. For example, the data produced for the `fqdn` value `site1.org` should look like this based on this example data (this is just a subset of what I would expect, there should also be rows for the other `fqdn` values as well)

```
fqdn        source_list                                           source
site1.org   [public_source_a, public_source_b, public_source_c]   public_source_a
site1.org   [public_source_a, public_source_b, public_source_c]   public_source_b
site1.org   [public_source_a, public_source_b, public_source_c]   public_source_c
site1.org   [public_source_a, public_source_b, public_source_c]   public_source_d
```

Once I have the data in this form, I will simply drop the `source` column and then use `drop_duplicates(keep='first')` to get rid of all but one.

I dug up some old code that I used to do something similar about 2 years ago and it is not working as I expected it to. It's been quite a while since I've done something like this with Pandas. What I had was along the lines of:

```
    merged_frame['source_list'] = merged_frame.groupby(
        'fqdn', as_index=False)[['source']].aggregate(
            lambda x: list(x))['source']
```

This is behaving very strangely. While it is in fact creating `source_list` as a list/array, the data in the column is not correct. Additionally, quite a few `fqdn` values have a null/NaN value for `source_list`

I have a feeling that this I need to approach this completely different. A little help with this would be appreciated, I'm completely blocked now and am not making any progress with it, despite having what I thought were very relevant example blocks of code I used on a similar dataset.

EDIT:

I have made a little progress by just starting with the fundamentals and have the following, though this joins the strings together rather than making them a list:

```
    merged_frame['source_list'] = merged_frame.groupby('fqdn').source.transform(','.join)
```

I'm pretty sure with a simply `apply` here I can split them back into a `list`. But what would be the correct way to do this in one shot so that I don't need to do the unnecessary `join` and then `apply(split(','))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the data frame from the example above:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'fqdn':['site1.org','site2.org','site3.org','site1.org','site4.org','site1.org','site4.org','site1.org'],\
                 'source':['public_source_a','public_source_a','public_source_a','public_source_b','public_source_b','public_source_b',\
                 'public_source_d','public_source_c']})
```

Use groupby and apply(list)

```
df_grouped=df.groupby('fqdn')['source'].unique().apply(list).reset_index()
```

Merge with original df and rename columns

```
result=pd.merge(df,df_grouped,on='fqdn',how='left')
result.rename(columns={'source_x':'source','source_y':'source_list'},inplace=True)
```